# How to translate "note:" into Chinese?

Tags: word-requests

How is the word "note:" translated into Chinese within the following example?

> Summary of Findings
>
> 1. Finding 1
> 2. Finding 2
> 3. Finding 3
>
> **Note:** these findings were based on a first draft and may be updated later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, 'note' means "註". More precisely, it is a "附註" in the example

> [附註](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/56428/)
>
> *appended note; annotation*
>
> *[synonym] 註解 (comment)*

```
Note: these findings were based on a first draft and may be updated later.

註: 这些调查结果基于初稿，可能会在以后更新

附註: 这些调查结果基于初稿，可能会在以后更新
```

Comment: Excellent，this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!